# Intersect two object lists on a common property and then compare a different property

Tags: c#, list, linq, ienumerable

I have two lists

`List<objA> List1
 List<objA> List2`

I want to compare these two list on `ID` field, once a match is found I want to compare another field `Distace` amongst these two lists and grab the object with the lower value.

Using Linq isn't is not giving the result I want, atleast for the first part of the problem.

`var test = List1.Select(x => x.ID)
 .Intersect(List2.Select(y => y.ID));`

Comment: Where is your question? Would you show us the part of your code that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @Cid Made the question a bit more clearer and added the code

Comment: read about `IComparer`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do this with Linq. Firstly, join the two lists together with `Union`. Then, group them by the `Id` field. Lastly, order those sub lists by `Distance` within the grouping, and take the first one of each to get a list of objects by `Id` with the minimum available distance.

```
var aList = new[]
{
    new SomeObject() { Id = 1, Distance = 3 },
    new SomeObject() { Id = 2, Distance = 5 }
};

var bList = new[]
{
    new SomeObject() { Id = 1, Distance = 2 },
    new SomeObject() { Id = 2, Distance = 6 }
};

var results = aList
    .Union(bList)
    .GroupBy(a => a.Id, a => a)
    .Select(a => a.OrderBy(b => b.Distance).First());
```